# What is the proper way to escape bad data from link in javascript against xss

Tags: javascript, url

What is the right way to escape bad data the var "`$actuallinkk`" inside this java script

```
<a href="javascript:reportUser(\''.$actuallinkk.'&act=inviteadmin\')">Invite Consultant to this conversation</a>
```

this is what i did below, i don't know if is the right thing to tackle xss attack.

```
function noHTML($input, $encoding = 'UTF-8')
{
    return htmlentities($input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding);
}




$actuallinkk = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

 echo'<script>
function reportUser(repUrl) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to invite Consultant to this chat?")) {
   document.location = repUrl;
  }
}
</script>

';
echo'
<li><a href="javascript:reportUser(\''.noHTML($actuallinkk).'&act=inviteadmin\')">Invite Consultant to this conversation</a>
</li><br/>';


if($_GET["act"]=='inviteadmin'){}
```

[image: this is the output of the code]

Comment: How does `reportUser()` work? How are you decoding the content?

Comment: it just a prompt link that allow users to confirm request 'continue action or no' before getting action

Comment: i just want to be safe in this area '.$actuallinkk.' because user can add xss code to the main url in their url bar, then the actuallinkk will take both the link and the xss as current page link and add it inside the href attribute

Comment: i just want to escape bad data from the link

Comment: Ok, but what I meant was: once you encode HTML characters with `htmlentities`, you'll have to decode them at some point to use them. I suppose reportUser() will do something like `html_entity_decode()`. Depending on how you decode it and how you use it, that might be the vulnerable point. How about a whitelist instead?

Comment: You mean i should do it like this                 <li><a href="javascript:reportUser(\''.html_entity_decode($actuallinkk).'&act=inviteadmin\')">Invite Consultant to this conversation</a>
</li>           i just edit the post by adding the image how the link will look like

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the correct approach, and you are currently vulnerable to XSS via this payload:

```
http://example.com/yourscript.php/');alert('1
```

**Attack**

As seen above, an attack would be setting `$actuallinkk` to:

```
1');alert('1
```

Which results in:

```
<a href="javascript:reportUser('1&apos;&rpar;&semi;alert&lpar;&apos;1&act=inviteadmin')">
```

Now, this looks save enough, but it isn't. As the input is inside a HTML attribute context, the HTML parser will look at it and dereference the entities. It will then pass the result on to the JavaScript interpreter, at which point the code looks like this:

```
reportUser('123');alert('1&act=inviteadmin')
```

This will be executed, including the injected payload.

**Defense**

The above example shows why it is important to take the context into account when defending against XSS.

Inside a JavaScript context, you do not want to HTML encode, but instead escape all special characters with their hex values (see [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values)).

Comment: This is what i wanted to do before but the splash  [a-zA-Z0-9.?=&_:(/ this very one make it not to work)]       inside make the prg_match not to work. How can i implement the splash


$rawactuallink = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";


if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.?=&_:/]*$/", $rawactuallink)) {
$actuallinkk = $rawactuallink;
}
else
{
$actuallinkk = "";
}

Comment: but i'm using the noHTML function in the webpage hope is good or not

Answer (score 0):

This is what i finally did

```
 $rawactuallink = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.#?=&_:\/]*$/", $rawactuallink)) {
$actuallink = $rawactuallink;
}
else
{
$actuallink = "https://www..com/err";
}
```

Hope it make sense to use this

Answer (score 0):

Do things step by step:

You build your link on PHP, so you do `$actuallinkk  .'&act=inviteadmin'`

You then put this link in a javascript context, so you `json_encode` it with `'javascript:reportUser(' . json_encode($actuallinkk  .'&act=inviteadmin') . ')'`

You then put this Javascript String in an HTML context, so you `htmlentities` it with `<a href="<?php echo htmlentities('javascript:reportUser(' . json_encode($actuallinkk  .'&act=inviteadmin') . ')', ENT_HTML, 'utf-8'); ?>">Invite Consultant to this conversation</a>`

Last, you should not rely on `GET` to do something like "Inviting someone" (unless this link retrieves the page to do the invite). Doing the invite itself should be done by `POST` (so in a `<form>`).

---

Note that you shouldn't rely on `REQUEST_URI` as you did, since it may not contain any query string (like `https://duckduckgo.com`, it would result in a link like `https://duckduckgo.com&act=inviteadmin` which may even not resolve as the correct host). You probably know which page you're on, so use this directly (like `/mypath/mypage.php?myparam=myvalue`).

Comment: `<a href="'.htmlentities('javascript:reportUser(' . json_encode($actuallinkk)   .'&act=inviteadmin')', ENT_HTML, 'utf-8').'">Invite Consultant to this conversation</a>`
 not working

Comment: That's because you haven't properly copy/pasted what I answered. Double check what's around `&act=inviteadmin`. Btw, "the Universe is not working" calls for more details.